# Disable auto sorting selected values in Bootstrap duallistbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-duallistbox

I am working on adding bootstrap dual listbox controller in to web page. 
This is the code I used

```
<script src="~/js/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var dualList = $('select[name="duallistbox_laws[]"]').bootstrapDualListbox({
            infoTextFiltered: '<span class="label label-purple label-lg">Filtered</span>',
          });
        }
</script>
```

User can selected option from first box. but it is auto sorting in the second list box. I want disable auto sorting in second listbox

Ex.
Selected order is

[image]

But in the duallist box it showing with sorted values [image]

How can we disable auto sorting in second listbox?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm struggling with it also.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is what you're looking for but, I modified the *jquery.bootsdtrap-duallistbox.js* file and added a call to the *sortOptionsByInputOrder* function at the end of *refreshSelects* function:

```
sortOptionsByInputOrder(dualListbox.elements.select2);
```

The complete functions:

```
    function refreshSelects(dualListbox) {
        dualListbox.selectedElements = 0;
    
        dualListbox.elements.select1.empty();
        dualListbox.elements.select2.empty();
    
        dualListbox.element.find('option').each(function(index, item) {
          var $item = $(item);
          if ($item.prop('selected')) {
            dualListbox.selectedElements++;
            dualListbox.elements.select2.append($item.clone(true).prop('selected', $item.data('_selected')));
          } else {
            dualListbox.elements.select1.append($item.clone(true).prop('selected', $item.data('_selected')));
          }
        });
    
        if (dualListbox.settings.showFilterInputs) {
          filter(dualListbox, 1);
          filter(dualListbox, 2);
        }
        refreshInfo(dualListbox);
    
        sortOptionsByInputOrder(dualListbox.elements.select2);
      }

    function sortOptionsByInputOrder(select){
    var selectopt = select.children('option');

    selectopt.sort(function(a,b){
      var an = parseInt(a.getAttribute('data-sortindex')),
          bn = parseInt(b.getAttribute('data-sortindex'));

          if(an > bn) {
             return 1;
          }
          if(an < bn) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
    });

    selectopt.detach().appendTo(select);
  }
```

I had:

[image: Pic 1]

And now I have:

[image: Pic 2]

My intended order was teste9/teste11/teste10.

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this option:

```
sortByInputOrder: 'true'
```

**E.g.**

```
        var build = $('select[name="buildcontent[]"]').bootstrapDualListbox({
            nonSelectedListLabel: 'Non-selected',
            selectedListLabel: 'Selected for your display',
            sortByInputOrder: 'true'
        });
```

**UPDATE**

This still doesn't work!

Using this setting the RHS box maintains the order of selection:

```
sortByInputOrder: 'true'
```

but when I access the values with

```
$('select[name="buildcontent[]"]').val()
```

it sorts them again.

Driving me nuts. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourSelector').bootstrapDualListbox({
     sortByInputOrder: true
});

var yourArray = [];
$('#yourSelector').on('change', function() {
     $.each($('#yourSelector option[data-sortindex]'), function(index, values) {
         yourArray[$(values).attr('data-sortindex')] = $(values).val();
     });
});

console.log(yourArray);
```